# Redirect android screen inside an app

Tags: android, virtual-desktop, google-cardboard

I've developed different personal apps for android and now i'm interested in google cardboard project

So, would be possible to create an application for android to implement the same system of this project : http://www.vrdesktop.net ( windows only ). In few words mirroring the android screen inside another app that will split everything .. 
actually i don't know if there are some usefull api/ways to accomplish the job.

EDIT1: i've prepared a draw to better show the idea: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/15AYvjesIhZDTe5mfOmm5TzhRkyxmDA6L0jI9MzdKbB4/edit

Comment: As I knew, you need special privilege to capture screen (for mirroring) of an Android device by programming. This means that you need sign your app with the signature of device vendor, or get root privilege.

Comment: You may refer the sample code in AOSP "screencap". You need to run it with root.

Comment: isn't screencap only for screenshot? 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long researches i've found an open source project that is doing exactly what i was looking for:

https://github.com/frma71/sbs

P.S. Thank you for useless downvoting